Axiom of choice for function domain reconstruction
I know the following definition of the axiom of choice:

For each family $S$ of nonempty disjoint sets, there is a set $V$ (the
so-called selector) that contains exactly one element from each of the
sets belonging to the family $S$.

Let us define the function $f$ as the set of short Kuratowski pairs $(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ such that $a$ and $b$ belong to any sets and that if $(a,b) \in f$, $(c,b) \in f$ then $a=c$.
In general, if I have such a set (function $f$) and want to reconstruct the domain $D$ of the function $f$ based on it by creating a set containing the first element from each pair in $f$, do I have to use the axiom of choice? And if not, why not?

Why would you need to, and how could you, use the axiom of choice?  That would allow you to select one element from each set, but it would provide no guarantee of which one.  More to the point, as the saying goes, the axiom of choice is not required to choose the left shoe from a collection of pairs of shoes, but it is required to choose one sock from a collection of pairs of socks.  In your case the elements of the set are distinguishable; in fact, part of the point of an ordered pair $(a, b)$ is that you can extract the first component $a$ from it.

@LSpice this is exactly what I dont understand about axiom of choice - why if $f={ {a_1,b_1}, {a_2, b_2},... }$ (sets {a,b} of socks) we must use axiom of choice - but if $f={ (a_1,b_1), (a_2,b_2), ... }$ (pairs (a,b) of shoes) we not need to use axiom of choice? Where is the differece in terms of definition od axiom of choice given in my question - ?

It may help to think of what a perfectly deterministic machine can do.  If $f$ is a set of ordered pairs, then I can say "take the first element of each ordered pair."  That's a recipe that a machine can execute, and you can test it by coding it in your favourite programming language (I'd call it map fst).  If $f$ is a set of two-element sets, then there's no such recipe—I can't say "take the first element of each set", because the elements of a set don't come in an order.  And, if you try coding it in a deterministic language (i.e., no random choice), then you'll find that you can't.

(You could use the axiom of choice on a set of ordered pairs, but you don't need to, and, if you want to get the first element of each ordered pair, then it would be pointless; the axiom of choice is intentionally blind to the internal structure of the sets, so, if applied to ${(1, 2), (2, 3)}$, there's nothing to stop it from producing the transversal ${1, {2, 3}}$.  (Also, be aware that a function, regarded as a set of Kuratowski pairs, need not consist of disjoint sets; consider ${(1, 2), (2, 1)}$.))

@LSpice Thanks for your answer. I have just one more small doubt: if our set f = {{a,b}, {c,d}, ..., {y,z} } (the set of sets of socks) then by the reasoning you gave, a deterministic machine would have a problem - but supposedly AC is not required for finite sets (since in this case it follows from the other axioms of ZF) - ?

Yes, it is so. My argument was meant only to be suggestive of the difference. In a programming-oriented approach to mathematics, one might prefer (but I'm not an expert, and you shouldn't take this speculation too much to heart) to accept ACC, since the easiest way to prove that a set is non-empty is to give an element, and, for a sequence of sets equipped with such proofs, you can simply take from each set the element guaranteed in the proof.

Ordered pairs have the property that we can identify, in a uniform way, which coordinate is left and which one is right. This is the "ordered" in "ordered pair".
That is, a property $\varphi(x,y,z)$ codes ordered pairs if and only if for every $x$ and $y$ there is a unique $z$ such that $\varphi(x,y,z)$ holds. This, of course, can be extended to include parameters.
So, when we say that something is coding ordered pairs in set theory, e.g. $(x,y)=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$, there is a formula that we can prove satisfies the above.
In particular, if we have any collection of ordered pairs, $R$, then for every $z\in R$ there exists a unique $x$ and $y$ combination such $\varphi(x,y,z)$ holds. In particular, we can define the domain of $R$—that is the set of "left coordinates"—without using the Axiom of Choice at all.
